# Fibonacci Series in C Program where FIRST 2 numbers are given by user

Tags: c

When the first number is `1` and second number is `2`, and the length is `5`, it should be `1 2 3 5 8`. But then my output is always `1 2 1 3 4`. I can't seem to find the problem.

Another input is `2` and `5`. Output is `2 5 1 6 7`.  The 3rd number which is 1 shouldn't be there.  What should I change or add?

*This is already a submitted HW and yes its wrong I got the deductions already. Now I just want to fix this so I can study this.

```
int main()
{
  int i, lenght = 0, fib, sum, sum1, sum2, a, b, c;
  printf("\nFirst number: ");
  scanf("%d", &a);
  printf("\nSecond number: ");
  scanf("%d", &b);
  printf("\nHow long?: ");
  scanf("%d", &lenght);

  {
    while ((a > b) || ((lenght < 2) || (lenght > 100)))
    {
      printf("\nFirst number: ");
      scanf("%d", &a);
      printf("\nSecond number: ");
      scanf("%d", &b);
      printf("\nHow long?: ");
      scanf("%d", &lenght);
    }
  }

  printf("%d\t%d\t", a, b);
  printf("%d\t", fib);
  for (i = 3; i < lenght; i++) {
    if (i <= 1) fib = i;
    else {
      a = b;
      b = fib;
      fib = a + b;
    }

    printf("%d\t", fib);
  }
}
```

Comment: Learn to use a debugger and how to step through your code line by line. When you do that you can see what happens, and see the values of all involved variables and monitor how they change.

Comment: and also how to format code so people can read it :)

Comment: Note that the spelling of `length` does not contain the sequence `ht`.  It doesn't affect the compiler, but it does the people reading your code.

Comment: I know that the spelling is wrong. I was just lazy to spell it right throughout the codes. Hahaha. I spelled it right when I was doing the question tho 

Im still new to this peval, learned this just last month so I am still adjusting making my codes look neat. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is for study, issues with your code: you don't need to duplicate the calls to `scanf()`, simply initialize one of the variables to fail (which you did: `lenght = 0`) and let the loop do its thing; pick *one* indentation style and stick with it; if you're new to C, always include the curly braces, even when the language says they're optional; you (correctly) allow for a length of 2, but then print three numbers; your `if (i <= 1)` clause is a no-op as the loop starts with `for (i = 3;` so `i` is never less than 3.

Putting it all together, we get something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int length = 0, a, b;

    while (length < 2 || length > 100 || a > b ) {
        printf("\nFirst number: ");
        (void) scanf("%d", &a);
        printf("\nSecond number: ");
        (void) scanf("%d", &b);
        printf("\nHow long?: ");
        (void) scanf("%d", &length);
    }

    printf("%d\t%d\t", a, b);

    for (int i = 2; i < length; i++) {
        int fib = a + b;

        printf("%d\t", fib);

        a = b;
        b = fib;
    }

    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Note that the input error checking isn't sufficient to prevent problems.  E.g. `b` can be greater than `a`, but still mess up the sequence if you input random numbers.  You're assuming the user knows to put in two adjacent items from fibonacci sequence which is tricky to test.

Comment: OMG. Thank you. Learned something from you. :)

One of the requirements of the homework was that if the first number is lower than the second then it must start all over again.

Same goes with the length, if it is more than 100 or less than or equal than 2. 

and yes I am new.

And I guess my mistake was I over complicated my codes.

Thank you again sir :)

Answer (score 2):

The first time you print `fib` (before the `for` loop), you haven't assigned it anything yet.

Answer (score 0):

just add `fib=a+b;` before printing `fib` value.
Its a good coding habit to initialize all variable before using it(especially in C).

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems strange to me. I tried to simplify your code a bit. See this once:

```
int main()
{
    int a,b,next,last,i;
    printf("Enter the first Value:");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    printf("Enter the second Value:");
    scanf("%d",&b);
    printf("Enter the length of Fab. series:");
    scanf("%d",&last);
    printf("%d,%d,",a,b);
    for (i=3; i<= last; i++)
    {
    next = a + b;
    if(i<last)
    printf("%d,",next);
    else
    printf("%d",next);
    a = b;
    b = next;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Hope it's Helpful!!

Comment: I was just trying use a for loop for the fibonacci sequence. 

I just started learning this last month sooo my codes arent that neat.